# Angular 1.58 Component $timeout does not apply changes

Tags: angularjs

I have come across a problem when converting my code to use components. 
In the components controller I use a $timeout function to delay the update of a object. This works in a normal controller, but not within the component - the code is very simply:

```
this.settime = function(){
  this.showDisplay = {hide:true};
  $timeout(function() {
    this.showDisplay= {hide:false};
  }, 2000);
};
```

The problem is that the updated value does not get passed to the DOM, in this example $ctrl.showDisplay.hide gets set to true, but after the timeout is completed it does not go back to false. I have tried using  $scope.$apply(); to force the update but it has no affect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` you are referring to inside `$timeout` function is different than `context` which is there inside controller. While changing hide `property` of `showDisplay` object, you don't need to change the reference of the object, you could directly change the property.

```
var self = this;
self.settime = function(){
  self.showDisplay = {hide:true};
  $timeout(function() {
    self.showDisplay.hide = false;
  }, 2000);
};
```

**ES6 Version**

```
this.settime = function(){
  this.showDisplay = {hide:true};
  $timeout(() => {
    this.showDisplay.hide = false;
  }, 2000);
};
```

Comment: Or `.bind`! `$timeout(function() {
    this.showDisplay.hide = false;
  }.bind(this), 2000);`

Comment: @tymeJV yes, Thanks for heads up! Indeed 1st one would make more sense :)